# Is there a translation of Rashi on Shas in English?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, torah-study, rashi

BH

Where is there a translation of Rashi on Shas? I know there is one for Tosfot using summaries on Daf Yomi is there something like this for Rashi?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I often find myself using [themercava.com](https://www.themercava.com/app/books/metanav/12611). Click on the words of Rashi, and the translation of the highlighted line should appear at the bottom of the page.